# Advantages of removing includes which are already in precompiled header?

Tags: precompiled-headers

I'm aware of disadvantages, but is there an improvement in compile time when you clean your sources from *#include* statements which are already in precompiled header?

I understand that header guards (be it *#pragma* once or *#ifdef* guards) will ensure that headers which are redundant will be quickly skipped, but is there a slowdown when accessing the header file and checking for the guard? I'm working on quite big project and even minor speedups in small scale could help in big scale.

Comment: It definitely seems like it has the potential to speed things up, since every unnecessary `#include` means the compiler/preprocessor must (at the very least) open, read, and scan the entire header file to process the guards and notice it's not in effect. The only way to really know how much it will affect your build is to try it, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my test I inserted header files from precompiled header to the "Force include" field, but the compilation time was the same. So I don't think, than you can get any measurable benefit from removing includes.

Comment: Please precise your question.

Comment: I've tried similar tests and it looks like there is no difference in compile time, so I'll mark this as answer, thanks.