# Should I continue to include headers in my source file if they are already included in the precompiled header?

Tags: c++, include, precompiled-headers

Surprisingly, the only *really* similar question I found (*[Advantages of removing includes which are already in precompiled header?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23683014/3258851)*) only asks for possible compile time gains, and mentions there are disadvantages but without specifying what these might be. There are other [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3691077/3258851) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41614024/3258851) but these concern including headers in headers and not directly in translation units, so I wanted to ask specifically about this.

Consider:

**precompile.hpp**

```
#ifndef PRECOMPILE_H
#define PRECOMPILE_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#endif // PRECOMPILE_H
```

**precompile.cpp**

```
#include "precompile.hpp"
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "precompile.hpp"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "hello";
    std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```

**Are there any major recommendations** as to whether or not to explicitly include, in the source file, headers that are precompiled (`<string>` and `<iostream>` in my example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could argue that any source file should `#include` everything it depends on, regardless of what's precompiled.

Such an approach makes it easier to reuse code in other projects, that may not have those dependencies precompiled.